# Cognito confirmation code timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm registering my user on AngularJS with Cognito from Amazon WebService.

I have a very strange bug :

If users directly try to confirm them account with the verification code received by email they always have this error message : `"ExpiredCodeException: Invalid code provided, please request a code again"` eventhough them account is well confirmed in the user pool...

But If they register themselves and they wait few minutes to try to confirm them account its works perfectly !

This is how I confirm the verification code :

```
confirmRegistration: function(verificationCode, username, _poolData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(_poolData);
    var userData = {
            Username : username,
            Pool : userPool
        };
    cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(verificationCode, true, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                    alert(err);
                    deferred.reject('confirmation failled.');
            }
            deferred.resolve('successfully confirmed.')
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

How could I fixe it ?
Where is from this problem ?
Do there is a timeout to set somewhere ?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying it does *not* work when done immediately, only when they wait a while after receiving it? How long are they waiting in each case?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that, I've to wait almost a minute...